# Flowable: Where is the claim button?

Tags: flowable

I started a process, and it resulted in a "Review" task.

The message says press the Claim button (blue top right) - there is none? How to do?

[image]

Comment: Maybe zooming out. On chromium based browsers use ctrl + -

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I need to assign and choose "Allow Process initiator to complete".

[image]

Comment: Hi, i am facing the problem right now can you give little more detailed solution, i can't fint this Assignment box